# WooCommerce - Insert new line at (before) specific character in shipping method label

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to split the contents of the shipping method label to insert a new line character after the first open bracket `(` in the string. Example code below:

```
<ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
   <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_cpam" value="CPAM" class="shipping_method">
        <label for="shipping_method_0_cpam">Registered Mail (20-40 days delivery): 
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>
            0.00</span>
        </label>                    
   </li>
</ul>
```

So for all `ul.woocommerce-shipping-methods li label` elements I need to split anything after (and including) the first open bracket onto a new line. Is this possible?

From the above example, the resulting output should be:

```
Registered Mail
(20-40 days delivery)
```

If it's possible to add a function to my child theme `functions.php` file or over-write a WooCommerce template to do this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the below function to replcae the `(` character with a new line plus the bracket in the shipping label:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'add_shipping_label_line', 9999, 2 );
   
function add_shipping_label_line( $label, $method ) {
    $new_label = preg_replace( '/\(/', '<br/>(', $label );
    return $new_label;
}
```